Matching non-aligning TimeZone polygon with countries polygon in QGIS
I would like to have a countries layer where each country that is contained by a timezone has this timezone, otherwise (like the US) is split up into multiple polygons. For the output, I would like to use the country's geometry and not the timezone geometry.
My idea is to create a layer where each row uniquely identifies a country and a timezone. This means there can be one row for countries that are entirely within a time zone or multiple rows for countries that span multiple time zones.
I am using the timezone data from Natural Earth which can be downloaded here:
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/timezones/
For the countries layer I am using simply the world-layer from QGis.
The issue is these two layers are not aligned when a timezone follows a country border. As here at the border between Spain and Portugal:

I want the entirety of Portugal to contain the values from the one timezone without having these sliver polygons. I can't join attributes by location with the largest overlap (which was my first intuition), because of the countries that span multiple timezones. However, I also cannot split the world layer with the time zone layer beforehand because they don't line up.
I tried the snap geometries to layer-tool. Which works quite ok but still leaves me with some small polygons.
I thought about it quite a bit but didn't have a good idea. Any tips?



Snap Timezones to World. I use a tolerance of 0.02 (the units are in the units of the coordinate system = degrees)
The geometries of the timezones are snapped to the country borders:
40.42847,-6.85440:


Fix geometries on both the world layer and the snapped layer

Intersect the fixed geometries

If you get any small polygons that shouldnt be there (I get one), select them by area and Eliminate them into a neighbor



